# Get Values from String

Tags: java

I want to get some values from a String that looks something like this:

```
"ID=1923\nZ=19\nX=123\nY=102\r\nID=133\nZ=11\nX=14\nY=12r\nID=1313\nZ=121\nX=134\nY=19"
```

I need the ID,Z,X,Y.Does anyone knows a method to solve this problem.(I know that the it can be done whit StringTokenizer but the question is how.)

I need only the values of ID,Z,Y,X

int ID = 1923;
int Z= 19;
int X= 123;
int Y =102;

I dont want to have something like String = "ID=1923";

Cheers,

Comment: Have you tried using StringTokenizer, as you mentioned. If yes share the code, result, exception.

Comment: try some examples http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/

Comment: or try splitting on "="?

Comment: You could also try using a regex instead of StringTokenizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
String str = "ID=1923\nZ=19\nX=123\nY=102\r\nID=133\nZ=11\nX=14\nY=12r\nID=1313\nZ=121\nX=134\nY=19";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "\n");
while(st.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(st.nextElement());
}
```

Or if you need them stored somehow:

```
    String str = "ID=1923\nZ=19\nX=123\nY=102\r\nID=133\nZ=11\nX=14\nY=12r\nID=1313\nZ=121\nX=134\nY=19";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "\n");

    List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> zList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> xList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> yList = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(st.hasMoreElements()) {
        String tempKey = (String)st.nextElement();
        String tempValue = tempKey.split("=")[1];
        if(tempKey.startsWith("ID")) {
            idList.add(tempValue);
        } else if(tempKey.startsWith("Z")) {
            zList.add(tempValue);
        } else if(tempKey.startsWith("Y")) {
            yList.add(tempValue);
        } else if(tempKey.startsWith("X")) {
            xList.add(tempValue);
        }
    }
    for (List<String> list : new ArrayList<List>(Arrays.asList(idList, zList, xList, yList))) {
        for (String id : list) {
            System.out.println(id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex, if the order of the elements (ID, Z, X, Y) is always the same:

A class to hold the values (fields are public for brevity):

```
public class Something {
    public int id;
    public int z;
    public int x;
    public int y;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID=" + id + " x=" + x + " y=" + y + " z=" + z;
    }
}
```

Then, the method with regex can have the following content:

```
    final String input ="ID=1923\nZ=19\nX=123\nY=102\r\nID=133\nZ=11\nX=14\nY=12r\nID=1313\nZ=121\nX=134\nY=19";

    final String regex = ".*?ID=(\\d+).*?Z=(\\d+).*?X=(\\d+).*?Y=(\\d+)";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);

    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    final List<Something> somethings = new ArrayList<>();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        final Something something = new Something();
        something.id = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        something.z = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
        something.x = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
        something.y = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(4));

        somethings.add(something);
    }

    for (final Something something : somethings) {
        System.out.println(something);
    }
```

Which produces the following output:

```
ID=1923 x=123 y=102 z=19
ID=133 x=14 y=12 z=11
ID=1313 x=134 y=19 z=121
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf("ID")` - start postion

`from(startPosition,indexOf("\n");` - result.

recheck a position and find next case.

**`I dont love recursion :) but in that case i will be used here.`**

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = "ID=1923\nZ=19\nX=123\nY=102\r\nID=133\nZ=11\nX=14\nY=12r\nID=1313\nZ=121\nX=134\nY=19";

String[] values = value.split("\n"); \\ This gives ID=1923, Z=19, etc

for(String str : values){
    System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.indexOf('=')) + "\t" + str.substring(str.indexOf('=') + 1));       
}
```

Comment: I need only the values of ID,Z,Y,X

int ID = 1923;
int Z= 19;
int X= 123;
int Y =102;

I dont want to have something like String = "ID=1923";